# Why isn't the keydown event firing?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to attach an event handler to the keyDown event in a canvas element. Here is a simplified version of my code.

```dart
class CanvasFun{

  CanvasElement canvas;

  CanvasFun(this.canvas){
    print("Game is loading!");
    this.canvas.onKeyDown.listen(handleInput);
  }

  void handleInput(e)
  {
    //breakpoint is never hit
    print(e.keyCode);
  }
}
```

I've removed some of the drawing code. In my main function I simply query the canvas element and pass it to my CanvasFun constructor.

I've also tried doing it this way:

```dart
void main() {

  var canvas = query("#Game");

  canvas.onKeyDown.listen(handleInput);

  var canvasFun = new CanvasFun(canvas); 

}
void handleInput(e)
{
  print(e.keyCode);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the event is not firing is because the focus is on the document (or some other element like an input, for example). And in fact, canvas element even when focused does not fire an event. Some elements do, like input elements.

The solution is to listen to key down events from the document or window:

```dart
window.onKeyDown.listen(handleInput);
document.onKeyDown.listen(handleInput); // You already noticed this worked.
```

Answer (score 3):

John McCutchan has written a nice Dart package to help handle keyboard input. You can read more about it here: http://dartgamedevs.org/blog/2012/12/11/keyboard-input/

Note that this library helps you handle input "correctly". You do not want to do any "work" in the input handling, instead you simply want to register that a key was pressed. You can check the state of any key presses inside of your requestAnimationFrame callback.

Hope that helps!

Comment: the link seems broken. if this is the new link, please update. https://github.com/dartgamedevs/dartgamedevs.org/blob/master/source/_posts/2012-12-11-keyboard-input.markdown

Answer (score 2):

There exists a workaround to get the `canvas`-element accept KeyboardEvents:

[Problems handling KeyboardEvents on DartFlash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128275/problems-handling-keyboardevents-on-dartflash)

Once you add the `tabindex`-attribute to your `canvas`-element, it can get the focus and then it will receive KeyboardEvents.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like I can get it to work if I register the event on the document rather than the canvas element.

```
document.onKeyDown.listen(handleInput);
```